# Can you use Dropwizard's configuration framework without having to spin up a webserver?

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have two components to my application: A webserver and a command line application that share a lot of code and resources but start from two separate main classes. I want to be able to share my configuration from the server for the command line application so that I don't have to write separate configuration code for it. Is it possible to use Dropwizard's configuration bundle outside of the context of a server application?

Answer (score 1):

To start the HTTP Server, you provide `server` as a CLI argument to the JAR.

To add your own CLI argument runner, you would define a [`Command`](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#commands) class and provide that rahter than `server`

If you need access to the config file, use `ConfiguredCommand`